# Rails - Turbolinks - Callback

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, function, callback, turbolinks

I wonder if turbolinks have a callback function that you can use to call functions when turbolinks have finished rendering the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use page:change, checkout the documentation for more events, https://github.com/rails/turbolinks